# Why does protobuf-net calls the getter of a property during deserialization but setter was not called yet

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

I have a property which relies on a valid state of the object. I am ensuring this either during creation of the object or in the `OnDeserialized` function.

Now I got a magic exception during `protobuf-net` deserialization because the object was not yet valid because the getter of the property is already called during deserialization. Neither the setter was called nor the `OnDeserialized` method (`OnDeserializing` was called!)

I did convert from DataContractSerializer so SkipConstructor is to ensure identical behavior (I don't want to remove it). The code looks more or less like this:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true, EnumPassthru = true)]
public class MyClass
{
    [OnSerializing]
    [ProtoBeforeSerialization]
    private void OnSerializing(StreamingContext c)
    {
        // first in here
    }

    [OnSerialized]
    [ProtoAfterSerialization]
    private void OnSerialized(StreamingContext c)
    {
        //
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private AnotherClass[] NetworkValues
    {
        get {   /* Why here after OnSerializing? */ }
        set { }
    }
}
```

I don't get it. What is the getter used for during deserialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons

Firstly: Protocol Buffers essentially defines deserialization as "merge" - allowing data to be merged into existing objects, and allowing concatenation of two byte streams to be function as a merge. As such, becauses it assumes that it is doing a merge, *by default* what protobuf-net is doing, in the case of lists, is

- get the existing list, if one; else create a new list
- add any new elements to this list (pre-existing or new)
- assign the list to the property if it has changed

This behaviour can be overridden by setting the `OverwriteList` property to `true` on `[ProtoMember]`, which makes it always treat the property as a new list (so: pre-existing items will be lost)

---

Secondly, the library needs to support a very common pattern - read-only list accessors. This *isn't* really needed for arrays, but much of the code is applicable to both - but essentially:

```
private readonly List<AnotherClass> _networkValues = new List<AnotherClass>();
[ProtoMember(1)]
public List<AnotherClass> NetworkValues => _networkValues;
```

In this case, the *only* mechanism the library has to get the list is: the get.

As a side note: the library also wants to avoid *unnecessary* list allocations in this scenario, so even if there *was* a setter, it would prefer not to create a new list. But again - much of this doesn't apply in the case of arrays, as arrays will always need to be reallocated to resize them.

Comment: I read the firstly part - and asked myself: "it is an array not a list, what for". And you did even answer that question before I could post it. Thank you for the details!

Comment: @toATwork the default behaviour is to retain existing array contents, just like it would existing list contents